# PreferenceFragment / Activity crashes on navigating back

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have implemented a simple PreferencesFragment. But when the user navigates back, the app crashes.

the PreferencesFragment class:

```
public class AppPreferencesActivityFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public AppPreferencesActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}
```

}

The hosting activity:

```
public class AppPreferencesActivity extends ABBActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_preferences);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new AppPreferencesActivityFragment())
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

And here is the preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="firstname"
    android:title="@string/firstname_"
    android:defaultValue=""></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="email"
    android:title="@string/lastname_"
    android:defaultValue=""></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="email"
    android:title="@string/email_adresse_"
    android:defaultValue=""></EditTextPreference>
```

logcat:

> 10-31 16:32:50.374  24512-24512/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.preference.PreferenceFragment$3.onKey(PreferenceFragment.java:368)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7200)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1354)
>               at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2088)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
>               at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:250)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please add the error from Logcat when it crashes to your post.

Comment: logcat doesn't show anything... not a single line output

Answer (score 0):

Add your fragment transaction to the backstack like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new AppPreferencesActivityFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)//Add this transaction to the back stack.
            .commit();
```

Change to this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing shown in logcat, as i said not a single line

Comment: it means you need to set up your filter correctly in logcat, if it crashe it must produce a log. If you dont see the log, that is your real issue you need to fix

Comment: posted logcat: NullPointerEception

Comment: we getting there, just need to see more log, is this all?

Comment: i should mention an observation: It crashes in Genymotion Google Nexus 7 Android 4.2.2 but NOT CRASHES in Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.2.2, both with Google Apps installed and a gmail.com account.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a line of code which Amdroid Studio automatically generates and i did not notice:

In the activity, removing:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_preferences);
```

fixed it.